# Updating a single and the same item with amp-live-list

Tags: javascript, css, amp-html

I'm trying to show a single item with using amp-live-list. I need to show only one item and keep update it like every 10 seconds.

My solution for now is only showing first child element of `<div items>` but not very confident this is a proper way to do.

Here is fiddle which I created although you cannot see how amp-live-list works since fiddle update html source automatically. But I would like you to see the code so that to make it a bit easier to understand what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/shinyatk/pen/dRXZog)**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    <title>Hello, AMPs</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    
<style amp-custom>
  body{font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;}
  pre{background: #FFF8DC;padding: 10px}
    .amp-live-list-item{justify-content:center;display:flex;}
.blog{padding:0;background:#fff;width:300px;}
.blog p{padding:8px;margin:0;}
.match{background:#fff;min-width:0%;}
.side{display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:space-around;}
.content{font-size:2rem;padding:8px;}
.flag{padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;}
.amp-live-list-item{display:none;}
.amp-live-list-item:first-child{display:flex;}
    </style>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
    <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.1.js"></script>
    
        <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
    
    <script async custom-element="amp-live-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-live-list-0.1.js"></script>
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <p>I want to show only one element below. I hide the other two elements with css as below to show the most updated content.</p>
    <pre>.amp-live-list-item{display:none;}
.amp-live-list-item:first-child{display:flex;}
</pre>
    <br>
    <p>Not sure whether this is a proper way to do.</p>
    
    <hr>

    <amp-live-list layout="container"
    data-poll-interval="10000"
    data-max-items-per-page="2"
    id="amp-live-list-time">
      <button update
      on="tap:amp-live-list-time.update"
      class="ampstart-btn ml1 caps">Update</button>
    <div items>

 <div id="item3"
        data-update-time="20170610"
        data-sort-time="20170610">
        <div class="card blog">
          <a href="">
            <p>Night</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>


    <div id="item2"
        data-update-time="20170609"
        data-sort-time="20170609">
        <div class="card blog">
          <a href="">
            <p>Afternoon</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="item1"
      data-update-time="20170608"
        data-sort-time="20170608">
        <div class="card blog">
          <a href="">
            <p>Morning</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>


  </amp-live-list>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/
at the bottom:

> If you want to update existing list items, you need to specify via the
>   data-update-time attribute when the update has been performed.
>
> The following example will display a soccer match score whose content
>   is changed every time the amp-live-list polls the page on the server.

[image: screenshot]